Can't access Environment Variables on Vercel using JavaScript
I want to access env variables on Vercel using JavaScript (TypeScript). I have set them under /settings/environment-variables, but when i try to access them using process.env.TURSO_DATABASE_URL during buildtime I get undefined. I'm using @t3-oss/env-nextjs to validate my env variables, but it seems like, I can't even access them directly.
If I use the Vercel CLI to pull the variables into a .env file, all of them appear as expected.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

If you are trying to pass the environment variables to the server the naming convention does not matter, but if you are passing it to the client you need to add NEXT_PUBLIC_ in front of the names.
You can check all about variables here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

Thank you for your answer. I know, that i need to add NEXT_PUBLIC_ to environment variables that should be passed to the client. But i don't want my secrets or database credentials on the client. The problem is, that i can't read any environment variable on the server.

How does your  @t3-oss/env-nextjs env.ts look like?

It looks like in the docs (template from create-t3-app), just added a few variables. The problem isn't @t3-oss/env-nextjs. I can't access them via process.env.
